# Why do I get a runtime error when executing immediate command

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm perplexed by an error when I execute a stored procedure. The error is 'invalid relational operator':

```
    ...
    DECLARE
    varResult integer;
    varFilterString varchar2(1000);
    varSampleCode nvarchar2(80);

    begin
    --debug values
    varFilterString := 'auditflag=0' ;
    varSampleCode := 's00083';


--this command gives the runtime error:
    execute immediate  'select count(*) from samples where samplecode = :samplecode  and auditflag = 0 and :filter'  
    into  varResult  
    using varSampleCode, varFilterString ;
    ...
```

PL/SQL is not something I do very often, and I'm puzzled by it. Whhat is wrong with that line?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't like and :filter, you can't pass in an entire condition as a string, you can only pass the parameter to bind to.  To resolve you just need to append the string directly rather than passing it as a parameter.

```
execute immediate  'select count(*) from samples where samplecode = :samplecode  and auditflag = 0 and '  || REPLACE(varFilterString, '''', '''''')
into  varResult  
using varSampleCode;
```

Comment: Ok, understood now and thanks - but I still get a runtime error (ora-0900 invalid sql statement) when the line executes: execute immediate  'select count(*) from samples where samplecode = :1  and auditflag = 0 and ' || varFilterString
into  varResult  
using varSampleCode;

Comment: What happens if you run the query manually: `select count(*) from samples where samplecode = 's00083'  and auditflag = 0 and auditflag=0`?  I can't see an obvious error but I don't have Oracle available at the minute.

Comment: It's fine. The actual value of varFilter when I get the error is " submittercode='S' " which is passed by the calling application and quite legitimate. Could it be something to do with the embedded apostrophes?

Comment: That'll be it, you'll need to replace the single quotes with two single quotes.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that is it. Even if the value of varFilterString is set as " auditflag=0 ", I get the error. It's only when I execute the query manually that it works without an error.

Comment: Got it! I had mistakenly defined varFilterString as nvarchar2, when this is inadmissable for an execute  direct statement, where the string must be varchar only (ie not unicode).